# What would be the most efficient algorithm to find kth digit from right of a^b i.e a raised to power b

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I recently came across this question. I know the naive approach i.e to find a^b and then extract least significant digits of this number 'k' times.
I am looking for a better approach.
'a' and 'b' are integers.

Comment: What can your `k` be? Also, what can be the values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: From your problem description, you are able to calculate `a^b`, which means `a` and `b` should be small.

Comment: a,b and k could be any integer. For simplicity lets assume that value a^b will not cause arithmetic overflow

Comment: lets take this example - a=2,b=10 and k=4

Comment: First calculate 2 ^ 10. Can be done in O(log b) time complexity. Then the kth rightmost digit can be obtained by extracting the least significant digits of this number k times

Comment: @gg4u This looks like one of those "online programming contest" questions. If it is, please provide a link to the contest itself so it's clearer what the goal is. Also, if it's an active contest, you cannot (=should not) compete with answers you get from Stack Overflow - you should wait until it's closed (usually takes little time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naive approach breaks when `a^p < 10^k`, but `a^(p+1)` overflows. A solution which only requires `2*10^k-2` to fit into the variables is to write the `(a*a) mod 10^k` using [Russian peasant multiplication](https://web.archive.org/web/20180101093529/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.peasant.html). It calculates the product of `a*b` by multiplying a and dividing b with steps of two and hence prevents the overflow as you can take the modulus between each step.

Here is a c++ implementation of function calculating (a*b)%m without an overflow:

```
unsigned long long abModm(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b,unsigned long long m){
  unsigned long long res=0;
  a=a%m;
  b=b%m;
  while (b>0){
    if (b&1==1){//is b odd
      res=(res+a)%m;//collect the result
    }
    a=(a<<1)%m;//multiply a
    b>>=1;//divide b
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then you can use this to solve the problem as already suggested by others:

```
int kthDigit(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, int k){
  unsigned long long m=1;
  for (int i=0;i<k;++i) m*=10;
  unsigned long long res=1;
  for (int i=0;i<b;++i){
    res=abModm(res,a,m);
  }
  m/=10;
  return res/m;
}
```

The exponent calculation is O(b) you can do it in O(log(b)) with

```
unsigned long long res=1;
while (b){
  if (b&1) res=abModm(res,a,m);
  b>>=1;
  a=abModm(a,a,m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the special case that a is divisible by 10. If k < b the result is 0, if k ≥ b then it's the (k - b'th) digit of (a/10)^b.

Do the calculation modulo 10^(k + 1). Replace a with a modulo 10^(k + 1). With 64 bit arithmetic, the calculation is easy if k ≤ 18 and a < 2^32.

Comment: This is the exact solution I was thinking. But this only work if `k<18`

Comment: And why do you do modulo `10^(k+1)`...it should be `10^k`. (or do you assume rightmost digit to be 0th place)

Comment: @gnasher729 you said "If k < b the result is 0". let a=2, b=10, k=4. Answer in this case would be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Do the power by multiplying in steps, and in each step, discard the highest digits that will not influence the digit you're looking for. This will allow you to go beyond the integer size limitations of your implementation. In Javascript, which is limited to 2<sup>53</sup>-1, you can calculate e.g. the 9th digit of 999999<sup>999999</sup>.

```js
function powerDigit(a, b, k) {
    var c = 1, max = Math.pow(10, k);
    a %= max;
    while (b--) {
        c *= a;
        // if (c >= Math.pow(2, 53)) return NaN; // Javascript limitation
        c %= max;
    }
    return Math.floor(c * 10 / max);
}

document.write(powerDigit(9, 9, 9) + "<BR>");     // 3 ; 387420489
document.write(powerDigit(99, 9, 9) + "<BR>");    // 4 ; 913517247483640899
document.write(powerDigit(99, 99, 9) + "<BR>");   // 2 ; 3.697296376497267726e+197
document.write(powerDigit(999, 999, 9) + "<BR>"); // 4 ; 3.680634882592232678e+2996
document.write(powerDigit(999999, 999999, 9));    // 9 ; millions of digits
```

Comment: In return statement i think you mean (c * 10) / max

Comment: @gg4u Indeed. In JS that has the same result, but maybe some languages have stricter `* over /` precendence. Simply using `c * 10 / max` should work in any language.

Comment: nice answer. Thanks a lot. Please upvote my question.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find a^b then you divide this by 10^(k-1) and from result you find modulo 10 and you get your kth number from right.
Here i give example of c code:

```
double r=pow(a,b)/pow(10,k-1);
   int result=(int)r%10;
```